# EF Core DB first mapping PostgreSQL bit(1) column as BitArray instead of bool

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm connecting with EF Core to the existing PostgreSQL database. There is a non-nullable flag column `IsAvailable` defined as `bit(1)`. Scaffolded entity ends up with `BitArray IsAvailable` property where I expected it to be a `bool`. I tried changing the type manually but I end up with an exception when I query the data.

> The property 'Loan.IsAvailable' is of type 'bool' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I also tried playing around with the private field, `[NotMapped]` property, and `[Column("is_available")]` attribute on the field, but that was not working either. Has anyone encountered this issue before? What can I do about it?

**Column definition in entity configuration**

```
entity.Property(e => e.IsAvailable)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
    .HasColumnName("is_available");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueConverters` were what I needed, I stumbled upon them in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#the-valueconverter-class).

Ended up creating one of my own for this type of conversion.

**Converter definition**

```
public static class ConverterProvider
{
    public static ValueConverter<bool, BitArray> GetBoolToBitArrayConverter()
    {
        return new ValueConverter<bool, BitArray>(
            value => new BitArray(new[] { value }),
            value => value.Get(0));
    }
}
```

**Column mapping**

```
entity.Property(e => e.IsCurrent)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
    .HasColumnName("is_current")
    .HasConversion(ConverterProvider.GetBoolToBitArrayConverter());
```

And I swapped the property to `bool IsAvailable` within my entity manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bool non mapped property in c# as a proxy to bitarray if you cannot change dB type to boolean.

```cs
[Column("is_available")]
public BitArray IsAvailableField {get;set;}

[NotMapped]
public boolean IsAvailable {
  get {
    return IsAvailableField[0];
  }
  set {
    IsAvailableField[0] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Such a property can't be materialized in LINQ. `.Where(e => e.IsAvailable)` fails to translate to SQL query. Even if I leave it as `BitArray`, `.Where(e => e.IsAvailable[0])` can't be translated to SQL query...

Comment: Map IsAvailableField instead in linq

Answer (score 0):

Although it is implicit on djbobo's answer, the first change to consider in this case (if possible) is to turn the column on the PostgreSQL database into a `boolean`, which should be used to store boolean data.

Here is a good explanation:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156851/123694